# Creating a Spark DataFrame with a mixed csv data source

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I am trying to read the following file into a Spark Scala DataFrame

```
 2:
 2059652,4,2005-09-05
 1666394,3,2005-04-19
 1759415,4,2005-04-22
 ...
```

The first element is an item and following lines are: users, rating, timestamp

I want to end up with a DataFrame/DataSet with the following schema:

```
case class Rating(user: Integer, item: Integer, rating: Integer, timestamp: Timestamp)
```

I am able to read in the data using the following:

```
val csv = sc.textFile("/FileStore/tables/qxlh0gub1498510564366/mv_0000001.txt") 
val data = csv.map(line => line.split(":").map(elem => elem.trim)).toDF() 

+--------------------+
|               value|
+--------------------+
|                 [1]|
|[1488844,3,2005-0...|
|[822109,5,2005-05...|
```

But i am unclear about how to transform this to a Ratings DataFrame with the above schema?

Comment: Try val data = csv.map(line => line.split(",").map(elem => elem.trim)).toDF()

Comment: is there any defined record selector ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `wholeTextFiles` *api* of `sparkContext` to read the data in one line and then format the line to meet your need. Following code will give you ideas to get your desired output.

I am assuming you have text file with data as

```
2:
2059652,4,2005-09-05
1666394,3,2005-04-19
1759415,4,2005-04-22
1:
2059652,4,2005-09-05
1666394,3,2005-04-19
1759415,4,2005-04-22
```

The working code is

```
val csv = sc.wholeTextFiles("/FileStore/tables/qxlh0gub1498510564366/mv_0000001.txt")
var item = ""
val df = csv.flatMap(tuple => tuple._2.replace(":\n", "###").split("\n")).map(line =>{
  if(line.contains("###")) {
    item = line.substring(0, line.indexOf("###"))+"###"
    line
  }
  else{
    item+line
  }
}).map(line => {
  val array = line.split("###")
  val subArray = array(1).split(",")
  Rating(subArray(0).toInt, array(0).toInt, subArray(1).toInt, subArray(2))
}).toDF

df.show(false)
```

You should have output as

```
+-------+----+------+----------+
|user   |item|rating|timestamp |
+-------+----+------+----------+
|2059652|2   |4     |2005-09-05|
|1666394|2   |3     |2005-04-19|
|1759415|2   |4     |2005-04-22|
|2059652|1   |4     |2005-09-05|
|1666394|1   |3     |2005-04-19|
|1759415|1   |4     |2005-04-22|
+-------+----+------+----------+
```

I am using `case class` with *timestamp* as `String`

```
case class Rating(user: Integer, item: Integer, rating: Integer, timestamp: String)
```